# Incremental Powertransformation on big data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, bigdata, gaussian

I am trying to perform a Powertransformation using `sklearn.preprocessing.PowerTransformer` on a large dataset with a shape of roughly ~(15000, 850000). The dataset is gridded climate data divided into individual .npz files (retrieved another script. Could also have been .hdf or .nc). Each individual file has between 200-1000 rows and all 850000, corresponding to the timesteps and grid cells of the climate data, respectively.

My overall goal is to perform a PCA analysis of the data. Previous studies [Lim,2012](https://doi.org/10.1007/s13143-012-0012-8), [Zhao,2022](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/363482906_Spatial_mode-based_calibration_SMoC_of_forecast_precipitation_fields_from_numerical_weather_prediction_models) have stated that a lot of information is lost if the data is very skewed and not Gaussian like. For that reason I want to perform a powertransformation to give all columns a more gaussian distribution before performing the PCA analysis.

**My overall workflow looks like:**

*Preprocessing:*
Load one data file -> Perform powertransformation -> save file

*PCA:*
Loop over all files: Load one data file -> Perform PCA using `sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA` with `partial_fit()` to perform PCA on part of the dataset.

*Explore PCA patterns and temporal coefficients*

The problem is that the `sklearn.preprocessing.PowerTransformer` performs a featurewise transformation. Given all the data is float64, this would ~100 gb of ram, or ~50 gb is converted to float32. I only have 16gb ram on my computer. So I cannot read all files into memory and perform the transformation on all rows and columns at once. Is it possible to perform the transformation in bactches like for the PCA analysis?

Comment: You only have 15,000 samples? Incremental processing makes sense for large N. Why can't you apply PowerTransformer to subsets of your features? It's a featurewise transformation.

Comment: would it make sense to loop over the files and the just use `fit` on each batch of data? This means that the learned parameters (e.g., mean and standard deviation) might differ slightly between different batches...

Comment: I agree that `sklearn.preprocessing.PowerTransformer` performs featurewise transformation. The problems is each file roughly contains 1,000 rows and 850,000 columns. So I only have part of all the samples for each feature if I load in one file. I cannot load in all 15,000 rows and 850,000 columns., as it is all float data, so I would need around ~100 gb of ram to have it all in memory.
I can perform the powertransformation by fitting for each file individually, but then all samples of a feature will not get the same transformation.

Comment: In that case, I would ask what your overall plan is for this data and what format your data is in. If you need to read all rows in anyway, can you read some of the columns from each file and combine them for transformation? You will likely need to provide details about your data, your attempted code (reading and processing data), your memory constraints, the ultimate goal, and the specific issue you are having to get an adequate answer.

Comment: `float32` dtype will get the size down to 50GB

Comment: I have updated the description to make the overall plan easier to understand. Thank you for the help so far!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a three step process:

1. For each npz file, which contains 200-1000 observations of 850,000 features, (approximately 1 to 6GB uncompressed) split these files up by feature group. Put the first 10,000 features in one file, the next 10,000 features in the next file, and so on. Each input file becomes 85 output files. You will end up with 6,000 files of about 20MB apiece.
2. Join together the sample files which have the same features. For each file, you would have 15,000 observations of 10,000 features. Write out the joined version. You would have 85 of these feature group files, which would be 1.2GB uncompressed.
3. For each of these 85 feature group files, load in the file, run PowerTransformer on that file, and write it back out as the transformed version. Since the file is 1.2GB, it fits in memory.